# Is it possible to set an environment variable for a user, not just a shell?

Tags: macos, environment-variables

I'm looking for a way to have some environment variables set for every application.

From what I read there are multiple possible files such as `~/.profile`, `~/bash_profile`, `~/.zshenv` etc.  But everything I can find seems to be about setting environment variables for the shell (i.e.: when I open a Terminal). Famously macOS changed from having default `bash` to default `zsh`.

I want to set these environment variables for my whole login, even GUI apps which are not (obviously) associated with any shell session.

I have, of course, tried `~/.profile` but this did not work. On Linux this would have been executed when I login, not just when I open a Terminal. Is there any such similar configuration file on macOS (11.3).

Apologies if this is trivial, I'm very experienced with Linux but very new to macOS.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36161817/151019

Comment: @mmmmmm that's painfully obscure.  Thank's for finding it for me.

Comment: There used to be a much easier way - but Apple considered it a security hole - which it could be - The idea is to only have things inside the apps control chnage the app e.g. by changing its preferences

Answer (score 2):

```
launchctl setenv key value
```

To make this take effect at login automatically, [create a launch agent to execute this at RunAtLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36161817/1549818).